# Connect old, possibly unsafe HDD to Windows 10 PC

Tags: hard-drive, security, virus, malware

I have an old HDD from my former laptop which I've been using until around 2013. Now, after 7 years, I want to connect it to my HDD (with a SATA - USB adapter).

I worry a bit about malware on said HDD as I was very young when I was using the laptop and had some viruses I know of (at least I thought I got rid of them whatsoever).

What would you recommend when connecting this HDD to my Windows 10 Computer? I don't have any additional antivirus installed, just using the Windows Security.

Are there any Sandbox Options for Windows 10 home or any other precautions I can take?

Answer (score 2):

*In theory* any malware that old should have been caught and catalogued by now, but I wouldn't let wishful thinking save the day.

If you *really* want to sandbox your machine then the best bet is to get a Linux distribution, install it to a USB memory stick, physically disconnect your current drive, and then boot the Linux distribution.

Many live distributions allow you to setup and update a virus scanner, so that should be able to get it started.

Once you are happy it is "clean", or at least not a threat, then simply copy off what you want to keep to another known clean device and wipe the old disk from Linux. Do not copy executables or unknown file formats if you don't trust them.

Alternatively if you haven't used it in 7 years then you obviously don't actually *care* about the data. If you don't trust it then simply take a hammer to the disk and remove all doubt that there is anything you could get back.